# How to make a GIF loop endlessly in Microsoft PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, gif, animated-gif

I need to make animated GIFs loop in Microsoft PowerPoint but when I present the slideshow the GIFs are static do not animate. I have looked for ways to change this behaviour but the advice is often to download specific software. Is there a way I can make a GIF animated in PowerPoint?

Answer (score 6):

First, ensure you are inserting the GIF [the way Microsoft recommends](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-animated-gif-to-a-slide-3a04f755-25a9-42c4-8cc1-1da4148aef01). This method is relevant for PowerPoint 2016, PowerPoint 2013 and PowerPoint 2010.

Select the slide that you want to add the animated GIF to.

1. In the **Insert** tab of the ribbon, click **Pictures**.
2. In the **Insert Picture** dialog box, navigate to the location of the
   animated GIF you want to add.
3. Select the file, and then click **Insert** or **Open**.
4. To play the animation, click the **Slide Show** view button on
   the task bar in the bottom bar of the PowerPoint window.

If your GIF does not loop or animate endlessly (i.e. it only loops once or a limited amount of times), then this might be because the internal setting of the GIF is only set to a limited number of animations ([source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_other-mso_2010/animated-gif-clip-play-once-does-not-loop-in-power/9f93c0bb-6fcc-47cf-9743-87049e69c6d0)). You will have to modify the GIF to change how many times the GIF loops. Microsoft recommends the online editor called https://ezgif.com/. Detailed instructions are [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-animated-gif-to-a-slide-3a04f755-25a9-42c4-8cc1-1da4148aef01).

Answer (score 0):

If your gif is set to loop then it will loop. Your comment about downloading is irrelevant.

Just create your gif as an animated gif with looping.

Comment: I meant if I copy it from a site like wikipedia..

Answer (score 0):

If the picture is from the internet, make sure to download it, then import it into the pp. Copy/paste from your browser to the slide won't preserve the looping animation.